# How can make Bootstrap dropdown menu working

Tags: bootstrap-4

So, I have an Angular app and I've copied Navbar from bootstrap script & pasted under menu compoment. Navbar work but I wonder drop down menu doesn't work. I'd like know how can I make this working. I also copied CSS, JS & Popper in the index.html as instructed by Bootsrap. Any can help me ?

menu.component.html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs- 
 target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" 
 aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
       <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
       </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs- 
    toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
        Admin
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Rooms</a></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="/">Another action</a></li>
        <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
   <form class="d-flex">
    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>
```

Comment: The reason is you're using Bootstap 5 data-bs- attributes which don't exist in Bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

It works since I copied the following script before the closing /body tag. The reason is, we need to apply jquery for animations.

```
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
 <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">    
    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->   
    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="/">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Admin
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rooms</a></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
          <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <form class="d-flex">
    <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
  </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </body>
</html>
```

Try adding this code. Since the order of the code is important, add all these after the closing tag of nav. And also as a reason for not showing the drop-down, I think it's because dropdowns are built on a third-party library of Popper.js. So, the dropdown menu does not work onclick but is working only on hover of the dropdown include popper.js, bootstrap.js, and bootstrap.css.

Comment: I copied your given code after the closing nav tag but it doesn't work. just fyi info I already copied same script in index.html